# Send empty body in POST request in Retrofit

Tags: java, request, jackson, retrofit

My api expects an empty json body (`{ }`) when making post requests. How do I set this up in Retrofit and Jackson?

I tried passing `null`, and empty string, and `"{}"` but could not get this to work.

```
@POST(my/url)
Call<MyResponse> createPostRequest(@Body Object empty);
```

How can I set an empty JSON body?

Comment: Have you tried without parameters?

Comment: Yes, it then sends a request without a body.

Comment: I guess you can create some empty class, e.g. `EmptyRequest` with singleton instance and pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty class will do the trick:

```
class EmptyRequest {
    public static final EmptyRequest INSTANCE = new EmptyRequest();
}

interface My Service {

    @POST("my/url")
    Call<MyResponse> createPostRequest(@Body EmptyRequest request);

}

myService.createPostRequest(EmptyRequest.INSTANCE);
```

Answer (score 11):

An empty Object does it for **Kotlin**:

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("your.url")
    fun createPostRequest(@Body body: Any = Object()): Call<YourResponseType>
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this . It worked for me now.

```
@POST(my/url)
Call<MyResponse> createPostRequest(@Body Hashmap );
```

while using this method pass `new HasMap` as paremater

```
apiservice.createPostRequest(new HashMap())
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I found a more suitable solution by using a `okhttp3.Interceptor` that adds an empty body if no body is present. This solution does not require you to add an extra parameter for an empty `@Body`.

Example:

```
Interceptor interceptor = chain -> {
    Request         oldRequest = chain.request();
    Request.Builder newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder();

    if ("POST".equals(oldRequest.method()) && (oldRequest.body() == null || oldRequest.body().contentLength() <= 0)) {
        newRequest.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{}"));
    }

    return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
};
```

You can then create an instance of your service like so:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client.addInterceptor(interceptor);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("YourURL")
        .client(client.build())
        .build();

MyService service = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
@POST("something")
Call<MyResponse> createPostRequest(@Body Object o);
```

then call:

```
createPostRequest(new Object())
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer in Kotlin:

```
    @POST("CountriesList")
fun getCountriesNew(@Body body: HashMap<String, String>) : Call<CountryModel>

      val call = RetrofitClient.apiInterface.getCountriesNew(HashMap())
```

Answer (score 0):

Following one is the easiest one I believe.

```
"{}".toRequestBody() // here "{}" will work like an empty json body.

// For Example:

val requestBody = "{}".toRequestBody()
val response = apiService.sendData(requestBody)
```