# Android RetroFit: 400 Response

Tags: android, retrofit

I am plugging Retrofit into my android app.

Here is how I build retrofit, notice the interceptor for the logging and headers.

```
 public void buildRetrofit(String token){
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .header("api-version", "1")
                        .method(chain.request().method(), chain.request().body())
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        });

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit.Builder buidler = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("XXX_HIDDEN_FORSTACKOVERFLOW")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build());

        retroFit = buidler.build();
    }
```

I make the call like so

```
 OrderApi orderApi = mainActivity.retroFit.create(OrderApi.class);
        Call<Order> call = orderApi.getOpenOrder();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Order>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Order> call, Response<Order> response) {
                Order a = response.body();

                int b = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Order> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

And here is how the actual request tag

```
public interface OrderApi {

    @POST("/HIDDEN")
    Call<Order> getOpenOrder();
}
```

Lastly, here is the order class

```
public class Order {

    private String orderId;
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    public String getOrderId(){
        return orderId;
    }

    public OrderStatus getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }
}
```

I get a response of 400. I have no idea why, and It works in postman etc. Something to note is that the response contains a lot more properties than just the ones in the class. I just want a proof on concept, but that shouldn't break things right?

.................
Managed to fix it. Had to send an empty body request as it was a post but I wasn't posting anything. API is dumb.

See here to send empty request [Send empty body in POST request in Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576046/send-empty-body-in-post-request-in-retrofit)

Comment: Can you show your Order class and an example json?

Comment: Edited. Btw, the real response returns a lot more properties, but that shouldn't stop me getting the response right? That should only fail the mapping of the response?

Comment: I think you cant post without @Body. // Btw, if you wanna hide your base url for stackoverflow, hide it from image aswell. :D